# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS when use catchAll in yii2

Tags: yii2

I'm using yii2 advanced 2.0.15.
os: win 10

in common/config/main.php when I try to use catchAll I'll get `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error

```
    'catchAll'=>[
    'site/offline'
]
```

site controller:

```
public function actionOffline()
{
    return $this->render('offline');
}
```

why does it happen?

**update:**

when I use another controller rather than SiteController it works fine.

why it doens't work on site controller?!

Comment: "works fine" meaning it shows the "offline" page? Is YII_DEBUG off?

Comment: can you share your complete config for **`common/config/main.php`** and **`frontend/config/main.php`** , also add the `behavior()` method for the `**SiteController**`

Comment: @ldg yes. YII_DEBUG is on and YII_ENV is dev

Comment: Try it without debug mode, catchAll docs notes that can cause issues.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam it's yii2 advanced without any change and i'm doing this in backend(just for test).
- 
http://pasted.co/e48cda28
-
http://pasted.co/ce938723
 - 
http://pasted.co/057614e3

Comment: @ldg same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is probably your rules of `AccessControl` behavior. There is no `allow` rule for `offline` action, so user is redirected to `login` action, which is caught by `catchAll` and redirected again. Change your first rule to:

```
[
    'actions' => ['login', 'error', 'offline'], 
    'allow' => true,
],
```

Comment: that is not correct it will throw `403 Forbidden` if not allowed rather than `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`, and when `catchAll` is specified nothing else than the specified action is every request redirected to. it does not go this route you are telling

Comment: `403` is thrown only for logged users - guests will be redirected to login page: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/eb198413f22d67fc2ed213b2c469633ead50c08e/framework/filters/AccessControl.php#L153-L161 https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/eb198413f22d67fc2ed213b2c469633ead50c08e/framework/web/User.php#L437-L455